# How to redirect output from python

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am new to IronPython. I want to use it in my C# application. Basically, I am trying to copy all the stdout from IronPython and get it in something like a string. I have followed this tutorial - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seshadripv/2008/07/08/how-to-redirect-output-from-python-using-the-dlr-hosting-api/

But, The MemoryStream object is always empty.

What could go wrong?

Comment: Catch also the  error streams and be sure that there is no errors.

Comment: yes. There are exceptions in  ErrorStream, like 1] '((System.IO.__ConsoleStream)runTime.IO.ErrorStream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' 2]'((System.IO.__ConsoleStream)runTime.IO.ErrorStream).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' 3]'runTime.IO.ErrorStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'4]'runTime.IO.ErrorStream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'. I just noticed. In addition the Input,Output Streams keeps throwing Read/write TimeOutException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are change in API scripts.

To use IronPython in c#:

1) Install the Nuget package

```
  Install-Package IronPython.StdLib
  Install-Package IronPython
```

2) To run your demo, modify your code:

```
  // ScriptRuntime runTime = ScriptRuntime.Create();  //create is not available
    ScriptRuntime runTime = ScriptRuntime.CreateFromConfiguration();
```

3) The using assembly:

```
  using IronPython.Hosting;
  using Microsoft.Scripting;
  using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
```

4) Add the following to App.config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
  <configSections>
  <section name="microsoft.scripting" type="Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.Configuration.Section, Microsoft.Scripting"/>
  </configSections>
  <microsoft.scripting>
  <languages>
  <language names="IronPython;Python;py" extensions=".py" displayName="IronPython" type="IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext,   IronPython"/>     
 </languages>
```

I tested the code in vs 2013 and it's working without errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing this but it gives me exception, An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll while using  ScriptRuntime runTime = ScriptRuntime.CreateFromConfiguration();

Comment: It seems that errors in app.config. I have posted the sample code with configuration, review: http://pasted.co/7b3aa8ca

Comment: Thanks, it is working!! Could you please refer some IronPython practice tutorials to me??

Comment: IronPython is compliant with python 2.7 (lagging the current ver 3.5), You can find ebooks  for python / IronPython. Also the documentation in http://ironpython.net/documentation/ have examples..

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it.